# Image panel not repainted unless on system events

Tags: java, swing

A friend of mine asked me to help him with Swing, and I reached a point where I can't solve an issue. 
So, first I have an ImagePanel

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

  private Image img;

  public void setImage(String img) {
    setImage(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
  }

  public void setImage(Image img) {
    int width = this.getWidth();
    int height = (int) (((double) img.getHeight(null) / img.getWidth(null)) * width);
    this.img = img.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
  }

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
  }
}
```

And a `FileChooser`, which should open the selected image into the ImagePanel. It simply calls `setImage` of the `ImagePanel`. But the image is not painted. No combinations of repatint, validate and invalidate help.

However, the image is painted when the `JFrame` is resized (using the mouse).
So, the question is - what method is called on resizing (using the mouse), which makes the `ImagePanel` to be repainted successfully.

Comment: do you set up a JFrame at all? And if you do, can you post the code for that?

Comment: The JFrame is generated by NetBeans, so I found it odd to paste generated code. The ImagePanel is added to the JFrame, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IconImage is using MediaTracker to load the image asynchronously. At the point where you're calling repaint, invalidate, etc, the image has not finished loading.

In your paintComponent, replace

```
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
```

with

```
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
```

The Component class has an implementation of ImageObserver that will call repaint when the image has finished loading.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the image and painting it as you are in your code doesn't change the actual size of the component. Depending on the layout and setup of the containing frame, a few different things may be happening - your ImagePanel may be initially of size 0x0, and so doesn't display until you enlarge the frame and more space is allocated to the ImagePanel; or the ImagePanel is manually sized to a large size that doesn't fit within the starting size of the JFrame, in this case the ImagePanel may not be displayed until enough size is available after resizing.

Comment: Thanks. There was initially the resizing code, but I removed it in my attempts. Now, combined with Davon's answer, it works. I wish I had two green ticks :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling the repaint method [(documentation link)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()) will cause the panel to be repainted. This leads to an underlying call to paint, which is what is also causing the JPanel to paint when you resize it.

Comment: and when I manually call repaint, to either or both the JFrame and the Image panel, nothing happens.

Comment: Are you repeatedly calling setImage along with the resize, or is setImage only called once and then the window is resized? Maybe you could post some more of your code.